# Using a C++ library for a C application

Tags: c++, c

I have a command line (+HTTP interface) audio application in C, which currently is being compiled with gcc on Mac OSX, but which I would like to keep this application linux compatible.

However, I would like to use the freeverb3 library. This is in C++. I would prefer not to convert all my code to C++. I don't (as far as I can see) need to call any C code from C++, nor will I need to use C++ objects in my C code. Simple method calls passing arrays of doubles plus a few ints as arguments will be all that I need in terms of interaction from my main application an the C++ code.

From some quick googling, it seems that I can write a C++ interface module, which can then expose some c compatible functions that I can call to make use of freeverb3. I"ve written a micro example to see how this might work. For this example, I have a dummy c++ file called test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class test_class
{
  int a;

  public:

    int get_a();
    void set_a( int v );
};

int test_class::get_a()
{
  return a;
}

void test_class::set_a( int v )
{
  a = v;
}

static test_class *c;

extern "C"
{
  void init();
  void set( int v );
  int get();
}

void init()
{
  c = new test_class();
}

void set( int v )
{
  c->set_a( v );
}

int get()
{
  return c->get_a();
}
```

I have a dummy c file that calls the functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Forward declaratoins for extern "C" functions in C++ code */

void init();
int get();
void set( int v );

/* C language code that references functions in C++ code */

int main()
{
  init();

  set( 55 );
  printf( "value: %d\n", get() );
  set( get() + 12 );
  printf( "value: %d\n", get() );
  return 0;
}
```

And, I have a makefile that creates an executable.

```
test: test.o user.o
    g++ -o test user.o test.o

test.o: test.cpp
    g++ -c test.cpp

user.o: user.c
    gcc -c user.c
```

Is this a good way of using C++ code from C? Is there a better/more sophisticated/more traditional way of achieving this aim?

Comment: You need to be sure that the C++ runtime init is performed properly (e.g. dynamic initialization of static variables). One good way to ensure that is to have your `main` function in C++. There are a number of **[FAQ items concerning this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/overview-mixing-langs.html)**.

Comment: *I would prefer not to convert all my code to C++* - what is the main reason behind that?

Comment: @Bartek - I have written thousands of lines of C code, which fundamentally works. I will be using the freeverb3 library to add a few 'bells and whistles'.

Comment: Is not a good idea to create an executable called `test` ([already exists in Mac OSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/test.1.html))

Comment: @user3748029 Yes, but why can't you just switch the compiler to C++?

Comment: Actually, I prefer the errors from g++

Comment: I don't mind at all using the g++ compiler for my existing C code. I've read online that the g++ compiler is fussier, and this can expose bugs. That would be a good thing in my eyes. But, I don't want to restructure and rewrite thousands of lines of code from C into C++, as it will take a long time @Alf - I note your comment about the main() method and will put it in a C++ file.

Comment: Yeah, you don't have to rewrite the codebase, I'm far from suggesting it. "Converting to C++" might require fixing the compilation errors caused by switching, resulting in the "Clean C" subset.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Or even better, avoid having static variables since it has a lot of other drawbacks too.

Comment: @user877329: avoiding statics is decidely not better, because you don't control the use of statics in libraries that you use, including direct or indirect use of the standard library, not to mention the support machinery for `new` etc. in short it's not doable. it might seem to work, as UB often does.

Comment: Converting the codebase to C++ is a ridiculous idea.

Comment: @MattMcNabb have you read the following comments?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz yes. Re "why can't you just switch the compiler to C++", the answer is that C++ is not a superset of C. Working C code may break (sometimes without giving any compiler error). There's absolutely no reason to attempt this, given that it is possible to combine the two at the linking stage.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Most of the time, though, compiling as C++ helps to get rid of bugs instead of creating new ones. Gcc compiler made a move to C++ compilation, and I think the outcome was very positive in general. Code quality improvements because of C++ strictness are a reason enough for me. And it's also quite simple to just run the compiled binary anyway, the tests will show if anything breaks. It's a bit of effort, but worth it in the long run.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz "Code quality improvements because of C++ strictness" is a myth. Perhaps there was originally a seed of truth in that 20 years ago `gcc` was pretty crap at supplying diagnostics required by the C standard. I challenge you to provide any code with a problem that g++ diagnoses but gcc doesn't today (in standard mode), other than invalid aliasing via `void *`. On the other hand, it is easy to supply code that works in C but whose behaviour is subtly broken if "compiled as C++".

Comment: @MattMcNabb To be honest, I don't know how much further the gcc development has progressed. Instead, I'll just [point you to the rationale](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cxx-conversion) of its team, that finally spurred the conversion. I don't usually like appeal-to-authority-arguments, but in this case, they are the people that should ultimately know best.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz certainly it is easier to write new code in C++ than C. g++ is under heavy active development, so it may improve code maintainability to do a full re-write in the new, higher-level language.  I don't see any suggestion on that page that their plan is to use the same old C code but compile it with a C++ compiler. In fact they list some coding guidelines and a number of changes which would render the code as no longer being valid C.  If you want to suggest that OP rewrites his C code in C++ then that is a possible idea, although it's overkill if the only problem is this link.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to think about it the other way.
Write your higher level application in C++, invoke the C++ library where you want without complications and call all your current C modules from the C++ level.

IMHO, this is easier to achieve than doing the same with C as high level.

Comment: `+1`. The speed-critical parts can be in C, and it's way easier to express the main code logic in C++.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz For C-style code, there is no difference in performance between C and C++. Sometimes, C++ will perform much better since more is known at compile-time.

Comment: @user877329 Ah, I was too quick while writing that. I mistakenly wrote "speed-critical", where I really meant "low-level". You are completely right.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use more than one C++ object from C you need to pass an extra instance pointer (this) to the C wrapper functions:

```
struct A {
    A();
    ~A();
    void set(int);
};
```

The C wrapper:

```
extern "C"
{
    struct A* a_create(void);
    void a_destroy(struct A*);
    void a_set(struct A*, int);
}
```

You may also like to catch all C++ exceptions in the C wrapper functions and convert them to error codes.

Comment: I was thinking of using static variables defined in the C++ code to store information. The C code doesn't have to be aware of any objects, it's interaction will be to provide double arrays and a few ints, and read back the same. In cases of exceptions in the C++ parts, I'd just return an array of zeroes. It's the kind of application that pretty much would either be working or crashed, there isn't really a need to catch exceptions and do anything careful with them.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a pointer to your object instead of using a static variable.

C++ class:

```
class Foo
    {
    public:
        void doStuff();
    };
```

Common include file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
    {
#endif
    void Foo_doStuff(void* handle);

    void* Foo_create();
    void Foo_destroy(void* handle);

#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
#endif
```

Wrapper functions

```
void Foo_doStuff(void* handle)
    {((Foo*)handle)->doStuff();}

void* Foo_create()
    {return new(nothrow)Foo;}

void Foo_destroy(void* handle)
    {delete (Foo*)handle;}
```

Comment: You may like to use `struct Foo*` instead of `void*` to increase type safety.

Comment: I agree, there's no point in erasing the type on the interface; it's actively harmful.

Comment: Yes, i can do that. Given what I plan to do, I don't think there's much of an advantage over using static variables. I'm not going to have large numbers of objects created, probably only a few. But, I can do this if it's a better structure.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this goes from C to C++ but it is well worth looking into [Swig](http://www.swig.org/index.php)

Comment: Totally overblown in this case, IMHO.

Comment: Maybe someone will look this question up in future and will find that its just the job for them!?

Comment: Yes, this is probably too heavy duty a solution for what I plan to do, but it might be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Make an `extern "C"` wrapper in C++, e.g.

```
// myWrapper.h
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

     void func1(void);
     int  func2(void);
     void func3(char const *str_ptr, size_t len);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

---

```
// myWrapper.cpp
#include "myWrapper.h"
#include "your_cpp_library.h"

void func3(char const *str_ptr, size_t len)
{
    std::string s(str_ptr, str_ptr + len);

    call_cpp_function(s);
}
// etc.
```

In your C code you `#include "myWrapper.h"` and call those functions. Make sure that:

- The code in myWrapper.h stays in the common subset of C and C++
- You do not do any cross-boundary resource allocation

The latter might work but it's best to avoid it to be safe. The latter point means that if memory is to be allocated, it must be allocated and freed by the same side; e.g. you can't have the C++ side call `malloc` and give a pointer to the C side, and then have the C side call `free`.  You have to pass the pointer back to whoever allocated it and let them free it.

**Important:** as Alf says in a comment, you must have `main()` in C++ and use the C++ linker , when doing C - C++ inter-linking. This is not a big hurdle though; you can rename your C code's `main()` function to `main2()`, and have the C++ code do `extern "C" int main2();` and call it.

Comment: Thanks. That'll save me from having two different .h files.